# "separators" for nonplanar graphs embedded in the plane

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, embeddings, graph-drawing

Given a nonplanar graph $G$ drawn in the plane with crossings.
Does there exist a small subset $S$ of edges of $G$ such that after the removal of all edges that intersect or share an endpoint of an edge of $S$, each component of the remaining graph has  at most $\frac{2}{3}|V(G)|$ vertices.

Comment: What is "small" and what is the question?

Comment: @MoisheKohan  o(|V(G)) or even say o( $\sqrt |V(G)|  $ )

Comment: Something is missing in your last sentence. Maybe "is planar"?

Comment: You probably also want to bound the number of crossings, or have some other assumption like $k$-planarity.  Otherwise, every graph can be drawn in the plane with crossings.

Comment: @TonyHuynh I don't the problem is not about embedding it's about separators.

Comment: @HaoS My point is that the complete graphs do not have sublinear separators (according to your definition).

Comment: @TonyHuynh  My definition of separator is different it is, the removal of all edges that intersect or share an endpoint of an edge of $S$,  In laymens terms, I remove the region of the plane occupied by edges of $S$ 
It's not clear that a complete graph doesn't have this kind of "separator"

Comment: Ah, I see.  The question makes sense to me now.

Comment: You won't be able to beat $\Omega(|V(G)|)$ (take a grid and add an edge between two vertices at distance 4, which are not on the same face, in order to make it non planar).

Comment: @LouisEsperet, doesn't just taking a path from the middle node of the top to the middle node of the bottom plus a few more edges work?  Can you draw your example?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\Omega(\sqrt{|V(G)|})$ ! In your comment above you speculated that $o(\sqrt{|V(G)|})$ could be possible.

Comment: Ah yes forget I said  $ o(\sqrt(V(G)))$ lets just say $o(V(G)) $